# Install debian on lenovo x1 carbon (2019)

Tags: debian, system-installation

I have a new lenovo carbon x1 from 2019 that i am trying to install debian *stretch onto.  I have a debian bootable usb.

The only problem is that every attempt at installing debian produces a blank, black screen on the laptop.  I can access the grub terminal by pressing 'c' at the install selection screen, but there is no advanced or normal option that I have access to for installing the software which does not fail and display a blank black screen.

Is it possible to install debian on this laptop? If so, how is it done?

Comment: Why Jessie? Have you tried with Debian 9 (Stretch)? You might need a newer kernel though...

Comment: I think I meant stretch; I grabbed the iso from Debian’s main page for amd64

Comment: FWIW, I’m running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on the 2018 model, and I remember no particular difficulties installing it. Ubuntu 18.04 is allegedly based on Debian 10 (buster)/sid, although buster is still to be released.

Comment: @ozzy thanks man.  If the answer below fails, I’ll try that next...

Answer (score 2):

If you have an nvidia model then you'll need to append nomodeset on the line starting 'Linux' in the boot options, by pressing 'e'. If this works and you need to know how to make it permanent or install the correct drivers then let me know.

Comment: Ok... the drives I was going to use are in flux (I was trying something on another computer), so it might be a while

Comment: Thank you though; this has been a long afternoon

Comment: @bordeo have you tried again?